# How to recursively open all files except ones in hidden directories from within vim?

Tags: regular-expression, buffers

In my python project root folder, there are multiple directories, some of which contain hidden sub-directories specifying python virtual environments. I want to open all my python files recursively from the root directory *except* the ones that lie along any path containing a hidden folder. This is because I don't want to load any virtual environment specific python files as there are thousands of them - I only want to load my project's python files.

I tried running `:n [^.]**/*.py` but it doesn't work, it still opens all python files.

I also tried reading about the `**` wildcard in the docs, but I couldn't find how to make it match folders whose name matches a specific pattern (namely not starting with a `.`).

Comment: As pointed out by @D Ben Knobole, Maybe you need a fuzzy file opener like [fzf.vim](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim) or [leaderf](https://github.com/Yggdroot/LeaderF). Better, use language server protocol and navigate your code easily. I am sure you do not need to open all your project files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vim paths in that context are more like shell-globs than regular-expressions.

A simple solution in a *nix shell would be

```sh
$ vim **/*.py
```

(This needs `extglob` in bash, I think, but should work out of the box in zsh.)

Inside of vim, I'm surprised it would match hidden files in the first place, though `:help wildcard` is clear that it matches "anything."

If you can narrow down the patter, that might help (e.g., `src/**/*.py`).

Otherwise, you could use a more complex command:

```
:next `find . -not -path .env -name '*.py'`
:next `git ls-files '*.py'`
```

etc.

You could create a mapping, if you like:

```
nnoremap <keys> :next `find . -not -path '*/.*' -type f -name '*.'`<Left><Left>
```

etc.

These commands can become quite complex, depending on what you're doing, so I won't show all the variations here.

---

I'll just note as an addendum that I don't generally open all my project files at once; I focus on one or two, and sometimes over a long session (or over a persistent [session](/questions/tagged/session)) lots of files accumulate.

It *can* be handy to add lots of things to the arglist, however, to allow `:argdo` or `:vimgrep /.../ ##`. Depending on the case, using the quickfix (combined with `:grep` or similar) and `:cdo`/`:Cfilter`, etc., can be more useful/less invasive/easier to setup.

---

@filbranden points out [`wildignore`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27wildignore%27), which you could probably set to include `.*` to avoid matching hidden things.

---

In all honesty, though, I can't really reproduce the issue. In a directory like this:

```
.
├── .env
│   ├── a.py
│   ├── b.py
│   └── c.py
├── a.py
├── b.py
└── c.py

1 directory, 6 files
```

Running `vim -u NONE --noplugin --clean`, I have

```
:next **/*.py
:args
[a.py] b.py c.py
```

Comment: On zsh `vim **/*.py` doesn't ignore hidden files actually. The `next` command works, but I need to tweak it a bit to not include any hidden folder automatically (without specifying the name). I didn't know it can be paired with the find command. I'll make this modification and edit and accept your answer when I get the chance. Thanks!

Comment: @ZaidGharaybeh it does for me in zsh; could be different options or something.

Comment: @ZaidGharaybeh See [`:help 'wildignore'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27wildignore%27)

Comment: @ZaidGharaybeh I rejected your edit only because I felt you substantially modified some of the points I was making. I did try to include some of your points, though; if you feel you need to expound further on what exactly your solution was, you can write another answer. Edits are generally for improvement, and while I agree that some of your changes improved the post, others did not (IMO).